# Is there any alternative way to enqueue scripts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, scripting

After solving all problems I am stuck at a very simple problem in WordPress. That is enqueueing an stylesheet and js script. I am desperately looking for a solution. I don't know why this is not working. I think I am following the rules in codex but it's not loading anyways. Even I open the page source code to find those files but didn't find.
File name and locations are below:

```
popup_plugin
   |---- assets\
            |---css\
                 |--- styles.css
```

And js structure is same as above

Now here is the code i am trying.I am using singleton pattern to instantiate class.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array(SMARTPOPUP::getInstance(), 'init') );
class SMARTPOPUP
{
    private static $instance = null;
    public function init(){
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'frontEndAssets'));
    }
    public function frontEndAssets(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 
            'wpsgdprcss', 
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/css/styles.css', 
            array() 
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'wpsgdprjs', 
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/scripts.js', 
            array(),
            false 
        );
        $localizedata = array(
            'ajaxurl'       => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'noncesecure'   => wp_create_nonce(WP_SMART_GDPR_SLUG),
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'wpsgdprjs', 'wpsgdprdata', $localizedata );
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your js enqueue successfully?

Comment: @dipmala nope!nothing

Comment: I thought your code should work, so I tested it and it does work. I only changed WP_SMART_GDPR_SLUG to 'WP_SMART_GDPR_SLUG' since you probably forgot to include the define for it.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array(SMARTPOPUP::getInstance(), 'init') );
class SMARTPOPUP
{
    private static $instance = null;
    public function init(){
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'frontEndAssets'));
    }
    public function frontEndAssets(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpsgdprcss');
        wp_register_script('wpsgdprcss',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/css/styles.css',array() );
        wp_register_script( 'wpsgdprjs',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/scripts.js',array(),false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpsgdprjs');
        $localizedata = array(
            'ajaxurl'       => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'noncesecure'   => wp_create_nonce(WP_SMART_GDPR_SLUG),
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'wpsgdprjs', 'wpsgdprdata', $localizedata );
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you remove all code from js and have the simple alert in that file ? for css you can remove the all css and add the simple css of on body and than check. I think now there is issue with your script but not sure

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_plugin_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpsgdprcss', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/css/styles.css' ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpsgdprjs', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/scripts.js' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_plugin_enqueue');
```

Answer (score 0):

**I thought your code should work**, so I tested it. Specifically, I tested the following:

```
<?php /*
Plugin Name: Junk
*/
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array(SMARTPOPUP::getInstance(), 'init') );
class SMARTPOPUP
{
    private static $instance = null;
    public function init(){
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'frontEndAssets'));
    }
    public function frontEndAssets(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 
            'wpsgdprcss', 
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/css/styles.css', 
            array() 
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'wpsgdprjs', 
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/scripts.js', 
            array(),
            false 
        );
        $localizedata = array(
            'ajaxurl'       => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'noncesecure'   => wp_create_nonce('WP_SMART_GDPR_SLUG'),
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'wpsgdprjs', 'wpsgdprdata', $localizedata );
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

This generated the following style and script elements:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wpsgdprcss-css'  href='http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/junk/assets/css/styles.css?ver=4.9.6' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wpsgdprdata = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","noncesecure":"8b77af0183"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/junk/assets/js/scripts.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>
```

The only change I made was I replaced WP_SMART_GDPR_SLUG with 'WP_SMART_GDPR_SLUG' since you probably forgot to include the define for it.

**There is nothing wrong with your code itself.**

Are you sure that your code is being executed?

I don't think this matters but I am running WordPress Version 4.9.6 using PHP 7.1.17.